# Axios Interceptor on request does not wait for await function calls to be finished before proceeding with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have this interceptor code for all requests made using Axios. `instance` here is the Axios instance.

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const tokens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
  if (!tokens) {
    return config;
  }
  const accessTokenValid = Date.now() <= (tokens?.expirationTime ?? Date.now());
  if (accessTokenValid) {
    return config;
  }
  const refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;
  if (!refreshToken) { 
    return config;
  }

  const response = await fetch(`${some-endpoint}/auth/refresh/token?token=${refreshToken}`);
  const newTokens = (await response.json()).data.data;

  localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(
    {
      accessToken: newTokens.access_token,
      expirationTime: Date.now() + parseInt(JSON.parse(newTokens.expires_in)) * 1000 - 600 * 1000,
      refreshToken: newTokens.refresh_token,
    }
  ));

  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newTokens.access_token}`;

  return config;
}, (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Then, the `instance` will be used like this.

```
    return instance.get(
      "/users/" + id,
      options
    );
```

where `options` look like this.

```
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
          },
        }
```

The problem with the code above is that the first request after the token expires will always fail. Then, the value in `localStorage.users` will be updated and the second request will succeed because the value has been replaced with the new access token.

I don't want to use an interceptor in response to retry the original request. I want to handle the token refresh on request. After investigating it turns out that the sequence of HTTP requests happening is as follows.

- HTTP request to the endpoint `users`
- Then, HTTP request to the endpoint for the token refresh

This tells me that the `async/await` part in the request interceptor isn't working. How can I make it so that HTTP requests must wait for the interceptor to finish running first (including awaiting any async functions) before running the HTTP requests itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things I'd do differently here...

1. *Always* delegate the responsibility of adding the `Authorization` header to the interceptor. Your consuming code shouldn't need to know about it
2. Queue requests requiring a token refresh to avoid multiple refresh requests
3. Use Fetch or Axios for all requests. Mixing them just leads to a larger blast radius and more difficult testing

```js
// Create instance
const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: "https://echo.zuplo.io/" });

let refreshTokenPromise; // used to queue up requests

// Add interceptor
instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const tokens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
  if (!tokens) {
    console.warn("No tokens");
    return config;
  }
  const accessTokenValid = Date.now() <= (tokens.expirationTime ?? Date.now());
  if (accessTokenValid) {
    console.log("Token still valid");
    
    // Now add the header
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokens.accessToken}`;
    return config;
  }
  const refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;
  if (!refreshToken) { 
    console.warn("No refresh token");
    return config;
  }
  
  // Check for in-flight refresh requests and start one if required
  refreshTokenPromise ??= getRefreshedTokens(refreshToken);
  
  const newTokens = await refreshTokenPromise;
  refreshTokenPromise = null; // clean in-flight state

  localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(newTokens));

  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newTokens.access_token}`;

  return config;
});

// Auth requests
const authApi = axios.create(/* baseURL, headers, etc */);
const getRefreshedTokens = async (token) => {
  console.log("Refresh auth token");
  // return (await authApi.get("/auth/refresh/token", { params: { token } })).data.data.data;
  
  // mock data instead
  return delay({
    access_token: "new_access_token",
    expires_in: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), // +1 hour
    refresh_token: "new_refresh_token",
  });
};

// Mocks (localStorage doesn't work in Snippets)
const localStorage = {s:{},setItem(k,v){this.s[k]=v},getItem(k){return this.s[k]??null}};
const delay = (v,d=2000)=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,d,v));

// Demo setup
localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify({
  accessToken: "old_access_token",
  expirationTime: new Date(2020, 0, 1), // very expired
  refreshToken: "refresh_token",
}));

// Simulate simultaneous requests
[123, 456, 789].forEach(async (id) => {
  console.log("Getting user", id);
  const {
    data: {
      url,
      headers: {
        authorization
      }
    }
  } = await instance.get(`/users/${id}`);
  console.log("user response:", { url, authorization });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

You can see that the sequence resolves the refresh token first and only once before making the *user* requests with the updated access token.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on #1. I do plan on refactoring the legacy codebase so that the Authorization header is injected using an interceptor.

I understand point #2. Thanks for that although it's not included in my question, it does happen that my code does attempt to refresh the token multiple times when a page makes multiple requests simultaneously.

Noted on #3.

Comment: I have some follow-up statements/questions to make me understand better. On point #3, I can't use the same `instance` to get the refresh token even though the refresh token URL has the base URL as `instance`; instead, I have to create another axios instance with the same base URL to avoid infinite request interceptors to be called (although this is fine because there is `refreshTokenPromise` as a queue), right? This is what I'm picturing if the same `instance` is used: user API request -> interceptor -> refresh token request -> interceptor -> refresh token request -> interceptor -> ...

Comment: Although your code snippet does work, I am not sure why my code does not work. Essentially, your code still uses `async/await` to wait for the mocked refresh token request (the `delay` function) before running the requests. My code is doing the same thing, besides the potential problems mentioned. Why is it that yours works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @Richard regarding your 2nd comment, yes. You'll want to keep your authorisation requests separate from regular ones to avoid interception where it's not wanted. That's why I used `const authApi = axios.create()` in my answer (a separate _instance_). As for your particular problem, I don't know. You'll need to edit your question to provide a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)